# On cyclic decomposition of element in $S_n$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $S_n$ be symmetric group and $x\in S_n$ be a permutation of $n$ numbers. Let $|x|=p$, where $n/2<p<n$ is prime. Consider $1^{t_1}2^{t_2}\ldots l^{t_l}$ to be the cyclic decomposition of $x$. Is it possible that $t_1\geq p$?

Comment: Can you explicit the cyclic decomposition of $x$? What are the $t_1, \dots , t_i$?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net The cycle decomposition has $t_1$ $1$-cycles, $t_2$ $2$-cycles, and so on. The notation $1^{t_1}\cdots l^{t_l}$ is standard for this. The actual numbers in the decomposition are irrelevant.

Comment: The cyclic decomposition of $x$ of prime order $p$ has to be $1^{n-p}p^1$ (This follows from @whacka 's formula "order = lcm(cycle lengths)").

Answer (score 3):

I assume that your notation $\left|x\right|$ means the order of $x \in S_n$, and that by "cyclic decomposition" you mean the cycle type. Then, $\left|x\right|$ is the lcm of the lengths of all cycles of $x$. Thus, this lcm is $p$, so that each cycle must have either length $p$ or length $1$ (since $p$ is prime). Moreover, $x$ must have at least one cycle of length $p$ (since $\left|x\right| = p \neq 1$).

Now, assume that $t_1 \geq p$. Then, the permutation $x$ has not only at least one cycle of length $p$, but also at least $p$ cycles of length $1$. Altogether, these cycles contain $\geq p + \left(\underbrace{1+1+\cdots+1}_{p\text{ addends}}\right) = p+p = 2p > n$ (since $n/2 < p$) elements. But this contradicts the fact that $x \in S_n$. So we cannot have $t_1 \geq p$.